# Unquote string with multiple backslashes

Tags: go

From one source I get data in the following format (with leading double quote)

```
data := `"{\"u\":\"Mozilla\\\/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox\\\/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)\"}"`
_, err := strconv.Unquote(data)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

I need to unquote and convert it to json.
But due to trailing backslashes like here `Mozilla\\\/5.0` get error `invalid syntax`.

In PHP, it is converted via double `json_decode` like `json_decode(json_decode($data, true), true)`

How to do the same in go? Unescape this string properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string is double encoded JSON.  Use the JSON decoder to remove the quotes:

```
data := `"{\"u\":\"Mozilla\\\/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox\\\/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)\"}"`
var unquoted string
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &unquoted)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle error
}
```

Decode a second time to get the user agent string:

```
var v struct{ U string }
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(unquoted), &v)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: handle error
}
userAgent := v.U
```

[Run the program on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tg1SQLifRWh).

Answer (score -1):

can't you just use strings.Trim() and this way remove \ and " chars ? Then you would have to json.Marshall string ?